# GridView when the page is refreshed

Tags: asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I have a `GridView` and a `Button` in a web form.
I change `SelectCommand` of `SqlDataSource` when user click on the button.
Then the result has been shown in GridView. But when the page is refreshed, results changes. For example when user wants to change the page of GridView.
Why?

Comment: Elaborate on _" the result changed"_.

Comment: Sorry! I can't speak and write English very well.

Comment: Better if you can explain what changes in result does occur

Comment: bind the same datasource in the page_index change event,so that whenever page changes,gridview will be binded.Can you plz,explain the question little brief.

Comment: post your code behind please

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your data is bounded again to grid for every Page load.
Please make sure that the the setting the datasource and databinding is not done on every page load..

Put your code in (!IsPostBack) like this:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
Gridview1.DataSource=yourDataSource;
GridView1.DataBind();
}
```